# Dart data structures efficiency

Tags: dart

I have noticed that some Dart data structures implement `EfficientLengthIterable` like `List` and `Set`  but `Iterable` is not implementing it, so I have measured the taken time to calculate the length of `List`, `Set` and `Iterable` that containing 10000000 elements and the results was little strange for me.

Code:

```
void main() {
  listChecker();
  iterableChecker();
  setChecker();
}

var list = List.generate(10000000, (index) => '${index} + a');

var iterable = Iterable.generate(10000000, (index) => '${index} + a');

var setCollection = Set.from(iterable);

void listChecker() {
  final stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
  print(list.length);
  print('${stopwatch.elapsed} List execution Time');
}

void iterableChecker() {
  final stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
  print(iterable.length);
  print('${stopwatch.elapsed} Iterable execution Time');
}

void setChecker() {
  final stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
  print(setCollection.length);
  print('${stopwatch.elapsed} Set execution Time');
}
```

Results (each one in a separated execution):

- `List`

> 10000000
>
> 0:00:01.402543 List execution Time

- `Iterable`

> 10000000
>
> 0:00:00.001933 Iterable execution Time

- `Set`

> 10000000
>
> 0:00:06.180889 Set execution Time

It seems like the fastest one was the Iterable but the dart documentation says that about the length property of the `Iterable` class:

> /// Returns the number of elements in [this].
>
> ///
>
> /// Counting all elements may involve iterating through all elements and can
>
> /// therefore be slow.
>
> /// Some iterables have a more efficient way to find the number of elements.

So what is meant by efficiency when implementing `EfficientLengthIterable`? I know that not iterating over each element should be more efficient but how is this reflected to the usage of these data structures? is it means space complexity? what are the cases I should use a `List` over `Iterable` in terms of efficiency as it seems that `Iterable` is too much faster regarding the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#default-value):

> Top-level and class variables are lazily initialized; the initialization code runs the first time the variable is used.

Since you've declared each Iterable as a top-level variable, they aren't initialized until they are actually used; which means that you are implicitly *generating* them within your benchmarks. The `Set` is the one that takes the longest to construct, and that's why the benchmark for `Set` is taking so long.

Try this instead, and you should find the results are more what you would expect:

```dart
void main() {
  var list = List.generate(10000000, (index) => '${index} + a');

  var iterable = Iterable.generate(10000000, (index) => '${index} + a');

  var set = Set.from(iterable);
  
  listChecker(list);
  iterableChecker(iterable);
  setChecker(set);
}



void listChecker(List list) {
  final stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
  print(list.length);
  print('${stopwatch.elapsed} List execution Time');
}

void iterableChecker(Iterable iterable) {
  final stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
  print(iterable.length);
  print('${stopwatch.elapsed} Iterable execution Time');
}

void setChecker(Set set) {
  final stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
  print(set.length);
  print('${stopwatch.elapsed} Set execution Time');
}
```

---

However, also note that Iterable.generate probably still creates a list under the hood, and therefore it will probably be equally as efficient in its length calculation, it's just that an object which conforms to Iterable won't *necessarily* conform to EfficientLengthIterable.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the benchmark using the code below (Dart SDK version: 3.0.5 stable):

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  final clock = Stopwatch();
  print('Warm-up ...');

  // Warm up
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    clock.start();
    clock.stop();
    clock.reset();
  }

  final iMax = 10000000;

  print('Initialization ...');
  clock.start();
  final set = <String>{for (int i = 0; i < iMax; ++i) '$i'};
  final list = <String>[...set];
  final iterable = Iterable.generate(
    iMax,
    (index) => '$index',
  );
  // Access last element ensure initialization is complete.
  list.last;
  set.last;
  iterable.last;

  clock.stop();
  print('  ${clock.elapsedMicroseconds} us');
  clock.reset();

  late int length;

  print('Benchmark start ...');
  // Benchmark set:
  clock.start();
  length = set.length;
  clock.stop();
  print('  Set: ${clock.elapsedMicroseconds} us');
  clock.reset();

  // Benchmark list:
  clock.start();
  length = list.length;
  clock.stop();
  print('  List: ${clock.elapsedMicroseconds} us');

  // Benchmark iterable:
  clock.start();
  length = iterable.length;
  clock.stop();
  print('  Iterable: ${clock.elapsedMicroseconds} us');
}
```

A typical output shows that accessing the length is efficient for all three datastructures benchmarked above:

```
dan@ws42:~/Test$ dart iterable_benchmark.dart 
Warm-up ...
Initialization ...
  5877209 us
Benchmark start ...
  Set: 4 us
  List: 2 us
  Iterable: 4 us
```

It turns out that `Iterable` is an abstract class and `Iterable.generate`
is a factory constructor which returns a `_GeneratorIterable` which in turn extends `ListIterable`.

Comments:

1. To improve accuracy it is best to remove the call to the print function from the benchmarked code. It takes a few microseconds to access the length while the call to the `print` function uses several hundred microseconds on my machine.
2. I added a warm-up cycle since the first few calls to the Stopwatch functions took an unexpectedly long time.